# Counting one field of table in other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote a script in oracle. But it does not give me the result that i want.
I need this one, imagine i have two table. Order_table and book table.
My order table is like this

ORDER_TABLE Table

```
ID  TYPE_ID   VALUE_ID 
1    11       null
2    11       null
3    11       null
4    12       null
5    11       null
```

Book Table

```
ID  ORDER_TYPE    DELETED
1      1         F
2      null      F
3      5         F
4      5         F
5      4         F
6      4         F
7      3         T
```

My script is like this

```
Select *
From (
  Select Newtable.Counter As Value_id,
         o.Id As Id,
         o.Type_id As Type_id
  From   (
           Select (Count B.Order_Type) As Counter, 
                  B.Order_Type As Id
           From   Book B
           Where  B.Deleted = 'F'
           Group By B.Order_Type
           Order By Count(B.Order_Type) Desc
         ) newtable,
         order_table o
  where  o.id = newtable.id
  and    o.type_id = 11
)
order by id asc;
```

Result is like this.

```
Value_ID TYPE_ID ID
2          11     5
2          11     4
1          11     1
```

It is not showing that second and third id has 0 count, Have can i show 0 count too ?

Result should be like this.

```
Value_ID TYPE_ID ID
2          11     5
2          11     4
1          11     1
0          11     2
0          11     3
```

Comment: What is a relationship between order_table and book_table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do not use implicit `JOIN` syntax(comma separated), that's one of the reason this mistakes are hard to catch! Use the proper `JOIN` syntax.

Second, your problem is that you need a `left join`, not an `inner join` , so try this:

```
Select *
  From  (Select coalesce(Newtable.Counter,0) As Value_id,
                o.Id             As Id,
                o.Type_id        As Type_id
         From order_table o
         LEFT JOIN (Select Count(B.Order_Type) As Counter, B.Order_Type As Id
                    From Book B
                    Where B.Deleted = 'F'
                    Group By B.Order_Type
                    Order By Count(B.Order_Type) Desc) newtable
           ON(o.id = newtable.id)
         WHERE o.type_id = 11)
 order by id asc;
```

Comment: Is this query faster than previous one @sagi ? Thanks for your help. script solved my problem :)

Comment: @Jo_bast There isn't suppose to be a big difference . No problem:)

Comment: He has a typo in the count, didn't notice that. Fixed @MT0

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE order_table ( id, type_id, value_id ) AS
SELECT 1, 11, CAST( NULL AS INT ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 11, CAST( NULL AS INT ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 11, CAST( NULL AS INT ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 12, CAST( NULL AS INT ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 11, CAST( NULL AS INT ) FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE book ( id, order_type, deleted ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, NULL, 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 5, 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 5, 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 4, 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 4, 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 3, 'T' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT COUNT( b.order_type ) AS value_id,
       o.id,
       o.order_type
FROM   order_table o
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       book b
       ON ( o.id = b.order_type AND b.deleted = 'F' )
WHERE  o.type_id = 11
GROUP BY o.id, o.type_id
ORDER BY value_id DESC, id DESC;
```

**Output**:

```
VALUE_ID ID TYPE_ID
-------- -- -------
       2  5      11
       1  1      11
       0  3      11
       0  2      11
```

However, if you did want to use the legacy Oracle comma-join syntax then you can get the same result with:

```
SELECT COUNT( b.order_type ) AS value_id,
       o.id,
       o.order_type
FROM   order_table o,
       book b
WHERE  o.type_id        = 11
AND    b.order_type (+) = o.id
AND    b.deleted    (+) = 'F'
GROUP BY o.id, o.type_id
ORDER BY value_id DESC, id DESC;
```

But **please** don't as the ANSI/ISO joins are much easier to comprehend the join conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with a scalar subquery, which may or may not be more performant than the left join versions described in the other answers. (Quite possibly, the optimizer may rewrite it to be a left join anyway!):

```
with order_table ( id, type_id, value_id ) as (select 1, 11, cast( null as int ) from dual union all
                                               select 2, 11, cast( null as int ) from dual union all
                                               select 3, 11, cast( null as int ) from dual union all
                                               select 4, 12, cast( null as int ) from dual union all
                                               select 5, 11, cast( null as int ) from dual),
          book ( id, order_type, deleted ) as  (select 1, 1, 'F' from dual union all
                                                select 2, null, 'F' from dual union all
                                                select 3, 5, 'F' from dual union all
                                                select 4, 5, 'F' from dual union all
                                                select 5, 4, 'F' from dual union all
                                                select 6, 4, 'F' from dual union all
                                                select 7, 3, 'T' from dual)
-- end of mimicking your tables; you wouldn't need the above subqueries as you already have the tables.
-- See SQL below:
select (select count(*) from book bk where bk.deleted = 'F' and bk.order_type = ot.id) value_id,
       ot.type_id,
       ot.id
from   order_table ot
order by value_id desc,
         id desc;

  VALUE_ID    TYPE_ID         ID
---------- ---------- ----------
         2         11          5
         2         12          4
         1         11          1
         0         11          3
         0         11          2
```